# Is there a method to identify the audio channel layout?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

A video file has many channels, and each channel is contained in a stream, e.g.

```
libavutil      52. 38.100 / 52. 38.100
libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
libavformat    55. 12.100 / 55. 12.100
libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
libavfilter     3. 79.101 /  3. 79.101
libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.2 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.3 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.4 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.5 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.6 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.7 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.8 : mono
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/data/tmp/ff6.mov':
Metadata:
major_brand     : qt  
minor_version   : 537199360
compatible_brands: qt  
creation_time   : 2015-01-16 17:54:47
Duration: 00:01:54.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 160836 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le, 1920x1080, 154650 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-01-16 17:54:47
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
  timecode        : 00:59:55:00
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-01-16 17:54:47
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-01-16 17:54:47
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-01-16 17:54:47
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream #0:4(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-01-16 17:54:47
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream #0:5(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-01-16 17:54:47
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream #0:6(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-01-16 17:54:47
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream #0:7(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-01-16 17:54:47
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream #0:8(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-01-16 17:54:47
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream #0:9(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-01-16 17:55:17
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
  timecode        : 00:59:55:00
```

Is there a method to identify which stream represents the left channel, and which represent right channel, and so on.
Thanks for reviewing my question.

Comment: Looks like channel tags haven't been set. *Typically* it's a 5.1 stream + downmix stereo at the end, so FL FR FC LFE BL BR DL DR. See key [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Channel-Layout).

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya. Could the example be channels of 7.0 ? And, are there any clues to  identify whether it is 7.0 or 5.1 stream + downmix stereo?